# Having trouble unmarshaling this xml

Tags: xml, go

Trying to understand how to unmarshall XML in Go. Read through multiple examples and stackoverflow questions. What I want is a slice with the all the patches installed on the system. I can't even get the patches to unmarshal, no errors, just an empty slice. Probably doing something basically wrong, thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
<probe version="1.3" date="2012-03-26:17:10">
     <properties>
     </properties>
     <patches group="server">
        <file name="5002012-02-09CR00000server.jar"/>
        <file name="5002012-02-17CR00001server.jar"/>
     </patches>
     <patches group="client">
        <file name="5002012-02-09CR00000client.jar"/>
        <file name="5002012-02-17CR00001client.jar"/>
     </patches>
</probe>
```

```
type Patch struct {
    group string `xml:"group,attr"`
}

type Probe struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml"probe"`
    Patches []Patch `xml:"patches"`
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem I believe you have is the `xml` package not populating unexported fields. The xml documentation says:

> Because Unmarshal uses the reflect package, it can only assign to exported (upper case) fields.

All you need to do is to change `group` to `Group`:

```
type Patch struct { Group string `xml:"group,attr"` }
```

You have a working example here:
http://play.golang.org/p/koSzZr-Bdn

Comment: I wish I could up vote you more. That was the problem, I tried too many variations and made a typo along the way.

Comment: Happens easily. I've never used `xml` myself, but had a similar problem with `json` which also uses reflect. Glad to help!