# Reading XML with golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to read som XML with golang. I'm basing it on this example which works. https://gist.github.com/kwmt/6135123#file-parsetvdb-go

This is my files:

Castle0.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Channel>
<Title>test</Title>
<Description>this is a test</Description>
</Channel>
```

test.go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Query struct {
    Chan Channel `xml:"Channel"`
}

type Channel struct {
    title    string `xml:"Title"`
    desc string `xml:"Description"`
}


func (s Channel) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s - %d", s.title, s.desc)
}

func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("Castle0.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var q Query
    xml.Unmarshal(b, &q)

    fmt.Println(q.Chan)

}
```

Output:
 - %!d(string=)

Any one know what I'm doing wrong? (I'm doing this to learn go, so go easy on me :P)

Comment: And what happens? Or we should imagine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble unmarshaling this xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404985/having-trouble-unmarshaling-this-xml)

Comment: I added it as you wrote your comment :)

Comment: @Ainar-G I changed title and desc to Title and Desc but did not help :(

Comment: There is no "<Query>" in your xml, change to `err := xml.Unmarshal(b, &q.Chan)` (and check the error). https://play.golang.org/p/v5ZnTyKL5Q

Comment: BTW: In general, avoid `ioutil.ReadAll` (and never ignore it's error!) and instead use things `xml.NewDecoder` that can decode from any `io.Reader` while reading the data.

Comment: Thant was it :) No Query, thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other packages, including `encoding/json` and `encoding/xml` can only see exported data. So firstly your `title` and `desc` should be `Title` and `Desc` correspondingly.

Secondly, you're using `%d` (integer) format in `Sprintf` when printing a string. That's why you're getting `%!d(string=)`, which means "it's not an integer, it's a string!".

Thirdly, there is no query in your XML, so unmarshal directly into `q.Chan`.

This is the working example. http://play.golang.org/p/l0ImL2ID-j